# Android Studio tab foreground doesn't disappear

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox

[image]This happens when I try to find class usage using <kbd>Cmd ⌘ + Left Click</kbd> shortcut.
How to prevent this issue?

Comment: isn't it `Cmd ⌘ + Left Click` shortcut?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Hi I got the same issue on Arctic Fox MacOS when switching tabs with ctrl+tab command. I resolved this bad behaviour by removing the key mapping here:

[image: here they are]

The "weird" thing is that I can still switch tabs but that gray foreground is disappeared. Maybe we had a conflict in key mappings. Just try to find yours and remove it.

**UPDATE 10/14:
I needed to remove all keymap conflicts in order to remove this annoying behaviour also after AS restart**